# Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. + Enzyme + ForEach

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component which iterates over an array:

*//the field.id has the "name" string*

```
...
<form>
  {schema.fields.forEach(field => (
    <>
      <label for="name">{field.label}</label>
      <input type="text" id={field.id} name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" placeholder={field.placeholder}></input>
    </>
  ))}
</form>
...
```

And I'm trying to test if the input tag has been mounted correctly:

```
describe("Form Generator basic mounting", () => {
  test("It should create a basic input", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FormGenerator schema={schema} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
    expect(wrapper.find(`#name`).props().placeholder).toBe("Name");
  });
});
```

However, the following error appears:

```
Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

This error only happens when I'm inside the forEach (which is iterating over a valid Array)

Any help is welcome, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the forEach method was not iterating properly, once i changed to `map()` worked just fine